How to beep in Termux?
Making a script that will run in termux and should make the phone beep when conditions are met.
How do I make the phone beep from termux?
Things I have tried that didn't work:
$ tput bel
$ echo -ne '\007'
$ echo -e "\a"

all produced no sound and no output.
$ echo -en "\a" > /dev/tty5
bash: /dev/tty5: Permission denied

error and no sound.

I hope someone finds a way to enable the standard echo -ne '\007'  , but until then, this works:
$ pkg install sox
$ play -q -n synth 0.1 sin 880

Can also do
$ echo -e "#/bin/sh\nplay -q -n synth 0.1 sin 880" > /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/beep
$ chmod a+x /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/beep 

to make a simple "beep" command.

Even a visual bell would be better than nothing.
